# Getting count of permutations in a faster way

Tags: python, permutation

Using this code to get count of permutations is slow on big numbers as the partition part takes long time to calculate all the partitions for a number like 100 and because of all the partitions in the ram, it is very ram consuming. Any solution to get count of permutations in a faster way? Thanks.

If we have `get_permutations_count(10,10)` means all the permutations in the length of 10 using 10 distinct symbols and If we have `get_permutations_count(10,1)` means all the permutations in the length of 10 using 1 distinct symbol which going to be 10 as those permutations will be `0000000000` `1111111111` `2222222222` `333333333` ... `9999999999`.

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import partitions
from sympy import factorial

def get_permutations_count(all_symbols_count, used_symbols_count):
    m = n = all_symbols_count
    r = n - used_symbols_count
    while True:
        result = 0
        for partition in partitions(r):
            length = 0
            if 2 * r > n:
                for k, v in partition.items():
                    length += (k + 1) * v
            if length > n:
                pass
            else:
                C = binomial(m, n - r)
                d = n - r
                for v in partition.values():
                    C *= binomial(d, v)
                    d -= v
                # permutations
                P = 1
                for k in partition.keys():
                    for v in range(partition[k]):
                        P *= factorial(k + 1)
                P = factorial(n) // P
                result += C * P
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
print(get_permutations_count(300, 270)) # takes long time to calculate
print(get_permutations_count(10, 9) # prints: 163296000
print(get_permutations_count(10, 10)) # prints: 3628800
```

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible ([mcve]), because we don't know where `partitions`, `binomial` come from - please add the missing imports. Is that `sympy.partition()` or what? In any case please state the algorithm/formula you're using, maybe there are simpler closed-form formulae. Also see, all the many existing SO questions on computing partitions .

Comment: @smci imports added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687296/12750353) answer, you can find the derivation of efficient algorithms for counting the number of such permutation.

It is achieved by using a generalization of the problem to count sequences of a length not necessarily equals to the size of the alphabet.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache
def get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length, distinct, used=0):
    '''
     - n_symbols: number of symbols in the alphabet
     - length: the number of symbols in each sequence
     - distinct: the number of distinct symbols in each sequence
    '''
    if distinct < 0:
        return 0
    if length == 0:
        return 1 if distinct == 0 else 0
    else:
        return \
          get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-0, used+0) * used + \
          get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-1, used+1) * (n_symbols - used)
```

Then

```py
get_permutations_count(n_symbols=300, length=300, distinct=270)
```

runs in ~0.5 second giving the answer

```txt
2729511887951350984580070745513114266766906881300774347439917775
7093985721949669285469996223829969654724957176705978029888262889
8157939885553971500652353177628564896814078569667364402373549268
5524290993833663948683375995196081654415976659499171897405039547
1546236260377859451955180752885715923847446106509971875543496023
2494854876774756172488117802642800540206851318332940739395445903
6305051887120804168979339693187702655904071331731936748927759927
3688881301614948043182289382736687065840703041231428800720854767
0713406956719647313048146023960093662879015837313428567467555885
3564982943420444850950866922223974844727296000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: How do your parameters relate to theirs?

Comment: Would you provide a non-recursive version of this? On big numbers, I face recursion depth and LRU cache errors. Also, for me, non-recursive is easier to manage. Thanks.

Comment: Please, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70944763/12750353)

Comment: Still would appreciate the non-recursive version here too. With the linked answer, I could get the index of last permutation of each distinct, but that's an add up trouble.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what exactly do you need. A good starting point is to show how you can achieve what you want with the existing code and then ask what you need to update. Probably better in a separate question again. This will be almost a version control.

Comment: Seems I didn't clearly deliver what I want here. The answer that you've provided here, and it's result works without problem unless I start to increase the distinct and n-symbols and length, then overflow errors and other stuff start to appear which is typical with recursions. What I want is to have a non-recursive version of this answer and nothing different in the result expected.

Comment: If it is necessary, I'll ask this in a separate question?

Comment: Please do, and give more context, also, if you implement this in a different language it might be considerably faster.

Comment: Tried with java and go, they don't support big numbers that well (much slower than python default implementation of support of big numbers). With PyPy I've increased the performance almost 90 percent. In java have to use GMP library but wasn't successful. I'll ask another question about using java for big numbers and will link you there if you could help me with using GMP in java. The final code will be provided to make it as fast as possible to the public use with any programming language people could help with.

Comment: The new question >> https://stackoverflow.com/q/71170543/2123400