# Convert a recursive python code to a non-recursive version

Tags: python, recursion

The code provided here works unless we start to increase the distinct and n-symbols and length, for example, on my computer n_symbols=512, length=512, distinct=300 ends up with this error **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison** and then overflow errors if I increase the lru_cache value.
What I want is to have a non-recursive version of this code.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache
def get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length, distinct, used=0):
    '''
     - n_symbols: number of symbols in the alphabet
     - length: the number of symbols in each sequence
     - distinct: the number of distinct symbols in each sequence
    '''
    if distinct < 0:
        return 0
    if length == 0:
        return 1 if distinct == 0 else 0
    else:
        return \
          get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-0, used+0) * used + \
          get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-1, used+1) * (n_symbols - used)
```

Then

```py
get_permutations_count(n_symbols=300, length=300, distinct=270)
```

runs in ~0.5 second giving the answer

```txt
2729511887951350984580070745513114266766906881300774347439917775
7093985721949669285469996223829969654724957176705978029888262889
8157939885553971500652353177628564896814078569667364402373549268
5524290993833663948683375995196081654415976659499171897405039547
1546236260377859451955180752885715923847446106509971875543496023
2494854876774756172488117802642800540206851318332940739395445903
6305051887120804168979339693187702655904071331731936748927759927
3688881301614948043182289382736687065840703041231428800720854767
0713406956719647313048146023960093662879015837313428567467555885
3564982943420444850950866922223974844727296000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: What does "overflow errors if I increase the lru_cache value" mean?

Comment: Can you write it in closed form, calling `math.factorial` and `math.comb` or `math.perm`? It'll be very fast. Otherwise, turning a recursive function into an iterative one requires pushing and popping values on a list instead of the stack.

Comment: What is it that this is computing? The function name includes the word "permutations", but it doesn't seem to be about permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's mine:

```
def get_permutations_count_improved(n_symbols, length, distinct):
    if distinct > length or distinct > n_symbols:
        return 0
    ways = [1]
    for _ in range(length):
        ways = [used * (distinct - d) + new
               for d, used, new in zip(range(distinct+1), [*ways, 0], [0, *ways])]
    return ways[distinct] * comb(n_symbols, distinct) * factorial(distinct)
```

Speed comparison for some argument sets:

```
n_symbols length distinct   yours    mine
   300      300    270      0.62 s   0.012 s (~51 times faster)
   512      512    300        -      0.035 s
  1024     1024    600        -      0.22 s
  3000     3000   2700        -      6.0 s
```

In my last line you see I split the overall result into three factors:

- `comb(n_symbols, distinct)` for choosing which `distinct` out of the `n_symbols` symbols actually get used. That essentially gets rid of the `n_symbols` parameter, or think of it as compensating setting `n_symbols = distinct`.
- `factorial(distinct)` for the order in which the symbols get used first. This gets rid of the `* (n_symbols - used)` in your recurrence.
- `ways[distinct]` is the number of ways to build a sequence of length `length` with exactly `distinct` distinct symbols, where the order in which they get used first is fixed.

It might be easier to think of the `ways` table as two-dimensional: `ways[length][distinct]`. But for more memory-efficiency, I compute it row by row and only keep the latest row.

Benchmark and some correctness checks ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVXbjpswEH3nK0ZarRJ2nQiS3hQ1VdV@RhohA5OAFmxqm263P5@OMYZsS5JK5cGxZ@Ycj8@MnebFFFKsPzTqdDooWYMpaywNlHUjlelXQec5tCIzUlbaOyvVJhnPCnT@mpvCuzJZpwwOnACq5FUQfB6DczzAEU3SoKpbw00phU4y2QozF4l@qVPagkGF4mgKBnmpTUkbM2g15tso3ARA32w2635hAQNoA6KtU1QgD9CboBRgCgReNQVP0XiMY990vkkQUqqg8XuLIkOP8rn8ifP26wQ@5fIM8BEidx77KTStEhD5KJckbLcTQfErGhsCWGnswXb6F@TbYIB/1n8RjxVYRK4Gj1EID90MHv@fNO5JY0s6xpLa1hwGV9oloWZT8gfm1/qm75dztT55ZaU6N459NF2RZ/6iYQu7eN8tD4RObKUVF0ecO8pwxPrwTig62rAT9VFIygl8PtMOPGXu9GDWb9l/lc3c7eAJSCoGuwfLzyDa05wK0y33oUutT9uadh61pxzsrTzXatCIfMNdHfYh7e2Vt4eY1p/dqksQ3MHXArMn2lkpzIxArQNtZEOcqyiw5@WjhNbRC2g96aTHe7OL3u4C/GzQ3otLPckZ0PuUha9ACnVbXQaN7TaJ5lojvXyeZNvnwMCHs8HiYkIrzxd6Hoqaq6fgSg9TSuuIitwNq/dRcHc9@G28Ym4gxK3gOFq9Yf347nY4MbpMXCquiLZPbD26ftlFG9ts676SzrRfdo9/klXI1dwpZ@ncH8y84nWa800XffU2s/7Z3caOo1EllXN2v1zT842ZFLmGGdwDqWy5lkkieI1JEp5OvwE)):

```
from timeit import timeit
from functools import lru_cache
from math import comb, factorial

@lru_cache
def get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length, distinct, used=0):
    '''
     - n_symbols: number of symbols in the alphabet
     - length: the number of symbols in each sequence
     - distinct: the number of distinct symbols in each sequence
    '''
    if distinct < 0:
        return 0
    if length == 0:
        return 1 if distinct == 0 else 0
    else:
        return \
          get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-0, used+0) * used + \
          get_permutations_count(n_symbols, length-1, distinct-1, used+1) * (n_symbols - used)

def get_permutations_count_improved(n_symbols, length, distinct):
    if distinct > length or distinct > n_symbols:
        return 0
    ways = [1]
    for _ in range(length):
        ways = [used * (distinct - d) + new
               for d, used, new in zip(range(distinct+1), [*ways, 0], [0, *ways])]
    return ways[distinct] * comb(n_symbols, distinct) * factorial(distinct)

funcs = get_permutations_count, get_permutations_count_improved

# Check correctness
stop = 20
for a in range(stop):
    for b in range(stop):
        for c in range(stop):
            expect = get_permutations_count(a, b, c)
            result = get_permutations_count_improved(a, b, c)
            assert result == expect, (a, b, c, expect, result)

# Benchmark
n_symbols, length, distinct = 300, 300, 270
#n_symbols, length, distinct = 512, 512, 300
#n_symbols, length, distinct = 1024, 1024, 600
#n_symbols, length, distinct = 3000, 3000, 2700
for func in funcs[0:] * 3:
    funcs[0].cache_clear()
    t = timeit(lambda: func(n_symbols, length, distinct), number=1)
    print('%.3f seconds ' % t, func.__name__)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a bounty.

Comment: Welcome @Pychopath, that was a very good answer :)

Comment: @Bob You wrote the solution in this question, right? Thanks for that, partly because it made the *task* fairly easy to understand, easier than the earlier question you wrote it for :-)

Comment: Yes It was me @Pychopath it was me, I even provided an iterative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70944763/12750353), but the idea there was to give the complete table of counts, to used by other mehods, I recognize two differences in your implementation. You are not iterating over the zeros, building a triangular matrix. You add `new` instead of `new * d` and then you leave the multiplications to be performed in the end. This is good because all the intermediate values are smaller, thus, faster.

Comment: @Pychopath Could you help with this question? >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207863/getting-permutation-index-and-permutation-at-index-faster-than-the-provided-solu

Comment: @Eftekhari I'll try. Btw, are you doing this just for fun/curiosity, or do you need it for some project? Seems like an unusual thing.

Comment: @Pychopath Late reply. Thanks again for your help. It's for a personal project. Have a good time.